# Ruby question about # Signs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As seen here: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top for the file:

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Return a title on a per-page basis.
  def title
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if @title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Why are there pound signs before base_title and before Title? What are they doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called string interpolation. base_title is a variable, and the #{} characters denote that its value should be substituted in place of that marker.

Comment: Further info: It's not just variables that can be interpolated. Any valid Ruby expression can go between the curly braces.

Comment: And they get converted to strings automatically. (I can't even count how often I've seen `#{foo.to_s}`, which is completely unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

It's string interpolation. Eg:

```
name = "nobosh"
puts "Hello, #{name}."
```

Prints

> Hello, nobosh.